# makumba - Creating related entities at the same time

Tags: jsp, makumba

I would like to know if it's possible to somehow create two related entities at the same time (one submit) using [makumba](http://www.makumba.org).

Looking at the example on the website let's say I have a Company.mdd:

```
name = char[50]
```

and Department.mdd:

```
name = char[50]
company = ptr company.Company
```

What would be the easiest way to create a company and entity in the same time. Can I somehow have nested new:form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on http://www.makumba.org/page/MultipleListsAndFormsHowto#section-MultipleListsAndFormsHowto-HavingAnMakNewFormInsideAMakNewForm has just been updated to have a complete example of nesting .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nested newForms exist and you can use them like this:

```
<mak:newForm type="Company" name="company" action="companyList.jsp" method="post">
  Name: <mak:input name="name"/><br/>
  <mak:newForm type="Department">
    Department name: <mak:input name="name"/><br/>
    <mak:input name="company" value="company" type="hidden"/>
  </mak:newForm>
  <input type="submit">
</mak:newForm>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have `newForm` inside a `addForm`?